# jQuery validate domain name entry and remove leading characters

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a form text input, and using jQuery to validate a correctly formatted domain name, and if it exists, remove leading "www." from the entry.  I also have jQuery created fields if the user wants to add more.  The logic seems to work with the first domain, but not with any subsequent entries.  For example, if I enter "www.mysite.com", then the preview display is trimmed to "mysite.com".  If I then add another field, the second field will not show as trimmed:
[image]

If I edit the first entry (keyup), it doesn't keep the trimming effect:
[image]

Here's the jQuery I'm using:

```js
$(function () {
    /* ADD INPUT AND TEXTAREA FIELDS */
    var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var x = 1; //initial text box count
    $("#add_field_button").on("click", function (e) { //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        //console.log("add_field_button");
        if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $("#input_fields").append('<div class="form-row" id="domain_record_' + x + '" data-id="' + x + '"><div class="col-6"><div class="input-group mb-2"><div class="input-group-prepend"><div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-lock" style="height: 18px;"></i></div></div><input type="text" class="form-control" name="domains[]"><div class="input-group-append" id="remove_field"><div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-remove text-danger" style="height: 18px;"></i></div></div></div></div><div class="col-6 preview_domain"></div></div>');
            $("#paste_csr").append('<div id="csr_textarea_' + x + '"><hr /><label id="csr_label_' + x + '" for="csr_' + x + '"></label><textarea id="csr_' + x + '" class="form-control w-75" rows="9" disabled></textarea></div>');
        } else {
            $("#add_field_button").prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });

    /* REMOVE INPUT AND TEXTAREA FIELDS */
    $("#input_fields").on("click", "#remove_field", function (e) { //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault();
        var xid = $(this).closest('.form-row').data("id");
        $('#csr_textarea_' + xid).remove();
        $(this).closest('.form-row').remove();
        x--;
    });

    /* VALIDATE DOMAIN ENTRY */
    $('#input_fields').on('keyup', 'input[name="domains[]"]', function () {
        var thisValue = $(this).val();
        var validate = isValidDomain(thisValue);

        var isMultiDomain = false;
        // check if multiple domains
        if ($('#input_fields').find('.form-row').length > 1) {
            isMultiDomain = true;
            // console.log("isMultDomain = True");
        }

        // remove "www." from domain, but only if not multi-domain
        if (thisValue.indexOf('www.') >= 0 && isMultiDomain !== true) {
            thisValue = thisValue.replace(/www./, '');
        }
        console.log("thisValue: " + thisValue);
        if (validate) { //Valid input
            $(this).closest('.form-row').find(".preview_domain").html('<span class="d-block p-2"><i class="fa fa-check-circle text-success"> <strong>' + thisValue + '</strong></i></span>');
            $('#csr_label_' + x).html('<span class="text-success">Paste CSR for: ' + $(this).val() + '</span>');
            // console.log($(this).val());
            $('#csr_' + x).prop('disabled', false);
        } else if (!$.trim(this.value).length) {  //input was emptied, clear the preview 
            $(this).closest('.form-row').find(".preview_domain").html(' ');
            } else { //Infalid input
            $(this).closest('.form-row').find(".preview_domain").html('<span class="d-block p-2"><i class="fa fa-times-circle text-danger"> <strong>' + thisValue + '</strong></i></span>');
            $('#csr_label_' + x).html('<span class="text-danger">*Please correct the domain name*</span>');
            $('#csr_' + x).prop('disabled', true);
            // console.log("failed");
        }
    });

    /* WILDCARD SWITCH */
    $('#wildcard_input').hide();
    $('#domains_input').show();
    $('#wildcard_cert').on('click', function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#domains_input').hide();
            $('#domains_input').find('input').attr('required', false);
            $('#wildcard_input').show();
            $('#wildcard_input').find('input').attr('required', true);
        } else {
            $('#domains_input').show();
            $('#domains_input').find('input').attr('required', true);
            $('#wildcard_input').hide();
            $('#wildcard_input').find('input').attr('required', false);
        }
    });


    /* CSR GENERATOR SWITCH */
    $('#csr_input').show();
    $('#autogen-csr').on('click', function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#csr_input').hide();
            $('#csr_input').find('input').attr('required', false);
        } else {
            $('#csr_input').show();
            $('#csr_input').find('input').attr('required', true);
        }
    });

    /* EXISTING CSR SWITCH */
    $('#paste_csr').hide();
    $('#existing-csr').on('click', function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#csr_fields').hide();
            $('#csr_fields').find('input').attr('required', false);
            $('#paste_csr').show();
            $('#paste_csr').find('input').attr('required', true);
        } else {
            $('#csr_fields').show();
            $('#csr_fields').find('input').attr('required', true);
            $('#paste_csr').hide();
            $('#paste_csr').find('input').attr('required', false);
        }
    });

});


/* VALIDATE DOMAIN */
function isValidDomain(value) {
    var domainPattern = /^([*]{1}[.][^-][\w-]+[.](?:[\w.]|xn--[\w]{2,})+|[^\W_][a-zA-Z\d\-.]*[^\W][.](?:[\w]|xn--[\w]){2,}|[a-zA-Z\d]{1,}[.](?:[\w]|xn--[\w]){2,})$/i;

    if (value.match(domainPattern)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;

}
```

```css
input.dom_name {border-right-color: white!important;}
div#remove_field span {background-color: white!important;}
.switch {
  font-size: 1rem;
  position: relative;
}
.switch input {
  position: absolute;
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  clip-path: inset(50%);
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}
.switch input + label {
  position: relative;
  min-width: calc(calc(2.375rem * .8) * 2);
  border-radius: calc(2.375rem * .8);
  height: calc(2.375rem * .8);
  line-height: calc(2.375rem * .8);
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  user-select: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-indent: calc(calc(calc(2.375rem * .8) * 2) + .5rem);
}
.switch input + label::before,
.switch input + label::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: calc(calc(2.375rem * .8) * 2);
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
}
.switch input + label::before {
  right: 0;
  background-color: #dee2e6;
  border-radius: calc(2.375rem * .8);
  transition: 0.2s all;
}
.switch input + label::after {
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  width: calc(calc(2.375rem * .8) - calc(2px * 2));
  height: calc(calc(2.375rem * .8) - calc(2px * 2));
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  transition: 0.2s all;
}
.switch input:checked + label::before {
  background-color: #08d;
}
.switch input:checked + label::after {
  margin-left: calc(2.375rem * .8);
}
.switch input:focus + label::before {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 136, 221, 0.25);
}
.switch input:disabled + label {
  color: #868e96;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
.switch input:disabled + label::before {
  background-color: #e9ecef;
}
.switch.switch-sm {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}
.switch.switch-sm input + label {
  min-width: calc(calc(1.9375rem * .8) * 2);
  height: calc(1.9375rem * .8);
  line-height: calc(1.9375rem * .8);
  text-indent: calc(calc(calc(1.9375rem * .8) * 2) + .5rem);
}
.switch.switch-sm input + label::before {
  width: calc(calc(1.9375rem * .8) * 2);
}
.switch.switch-sm input + label::after {
  width: calc(calc(1.9375rem * .8) - calc(2px * 2));
  height: calc(calc(1.9375rem * .8) - calc(2px * 2));
}
.switch.switch-sm input:checked + label::after {
  margin-left: calc(1.9375rem * .8);
}
.switch.switch-lg {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
.switch.switch-lg input + label {
  min-width: calc(calc(3rem * .8) * 2);
  height: calc(3rem * .8);
  line-height: calc(3rem * .8);
  text-indent: calc(calc(calc(3rem * .8) * 2) + .5rem);
}
.switch.switch-lg input + label::before {
  width: calc(calc(3rem * .8) * 2);
}
.switch.switch-lg input + label::after {
  width: calc(calc(3rem * .8) - calc(2px * 2));
  height: calc(calc(3rem * .8) - calc(2px * 2));
}
.switch.switch-lg input:checked + label::after {
  margin-left: calc(3rem * .8);
}
.switch + .switch {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="container border my-5">
            <div class="row border-bottom ">
                <div class="col p-2 bg-dark text-white">
                    <h1>SSL Certificate Setup</h1>
                    <p>You’re on your way to issuing a brand-new SSL certificate for one or multiple domains.<br>Before you can install your new certificate, please complete the steps below.<br></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row border-bottom ">
                <div class="col p-2 " style="background-color:#EEE;">
                    <a class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapsewithlink" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapsewithlink">
                        Domains
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row border-bottom collapse show" id="collapsewithlink">
                <div class="col p-2">

                    <div class="form-check mb-4">
                        <div class="form-group">  
                            <span class="switch switch-sm">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="switch" id="wildcard_cert">
                                <label for="wildcard_cert">I need a wildcard certificate</label>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p>Please enter at least one domain to secure.<br>
                        For single-domain certificates the WWW-version of your domain will always be included.</p>
                    <div id="wildcard_input">
                        <strong>Enter Domain</strong>
                        <hr />
                        <div id="input_field">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group" id="domain">
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-lock" style="height: 18px;"></i></span></div><input class="form-control" type="text" name="domains[]" placeholder="Enter Domain">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="domains_input">
                        <strong>Enter Domains</strong>
                        <hr />
                        <div id="input_fields">
                            <div class="form-row" id="domain_record_1" data-id="1">
                                <div class="col-6">
                                    <div class="input-group mb-2">
                                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-lock" style="height: 18px;"></i></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="domains[]">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-6 preview_domain"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="add_field_button" type="button"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;Add</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row border-bottom">
                <div class="col p-2" style="background-color:#EEE;">
                    <a class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapsewithlink2" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapsewithlink">
                        CSR & Contact
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row border-bottom collapse" id="collapsewithlink2">
                <div class="col p-2">

                    <p>Before validation, we will auto-generate contact information and a CSR for your certificate.<br>
                        To enter your information manually or paste an existing CSR, please uncheck the box below.</p>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <div class="form-group">  
                            <span class="switch switch-sm">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="switch" id="autogen-csr">
                                <label for="autogen-csr">Auto-Generate CSR</label>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="csr_input">
                        <div class="form-check mb-4">
                            <div class="form-group">  
                                <span class="switch switch-sm">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="switch" id="existing-csr">
                                    <label for="existing-csr">Paste Existing CSR</label>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="paste_csr">
                            <label for="csr_1" id="csr_label_1">Paste CSR here</label>
                            <textarea id="csr_1" class="form-control w-75" rows="9" disabled></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div id="csr_fields" class="w-75">
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col">
                                    <label for="acme_email">Email Address</label>
                                    <input name="acme_email" type="email" class="form-control" id="acme_email" placeholder="" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label for="acme_organization">Organization</label>
                                    <input name="acme_organization" type="text" class="form-control" id="acme_organization" placeholder="" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label for="acme_department">Department</label>
                                    <input name="acme_department" type="text" class="form-control" id="acme_department" placeholder="" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                    <label for="acme_city">City</label>
                                    <input name="acme_city" type="text" class="form-control" id="acme_city" placeholder="" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                    <label for="acme_state">State</label>
                                    <input name="acme_state" type="text" class="form-control" id="acme_state" placeholder="" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                    <label for="acme_country">Country</label>
                                    <select name="acme_country" class="form-control" id="acme_country" required>
                                        <option selected="" value="" disabled="">Choose your country</option>
                                        <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
                                        <option value="AX">Åland Islands</option>
                                        <option value="AL">Albania</option>
                                        <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col p-2" style="background-color:#EEE;">
                    <a class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapsewithlink3" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapsewithlink">
                        Finalize Setup
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row collapse" id="collapsewithlink3">
                <div class="col">

                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation.

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated....I've also created a [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/shavertech/zotx5a7k/6/) with the full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.  I moved the logic that replaces 'www' up to the top so that validation happens afterward, and now it works for all entries.  Here's the change:

```
    /* VALIDATE DOMAIN ENTRY */
$('#input_fields').on('keyup', '.domain_input', function () {
    var thisValue = $(this).val();
    // remove "www." from domain, but only if not multi-domain
    if (thisValue.indexOf('www.') >= 0 && isMultiDomain !== true) {
        thisValue = thisValue.replace(/www./, '');
    }
    
    var validate = isValidDomain(thisValue);

    var isMultiDomain = false;
    // check if multiple domains
    if ($('#input_fields').find('.form-row').length > 1) {
        isMultiDomain = true;
        // console.log("isMultDomain = True");
    }
    
    console.log("thisValue: " + thisValue);
    if (validate) { //Valid input
        $(this).closest('.form-row').find(".preview_domain").html('<span class="d-block p-2"><i class="fa fa-check-circle text-success"> <strong>' + thisValue + '</strong></i></span>');
        $('#csr_label_' + x).html('<span class="text-success">Paste CSR for: ' + $(this).val() + '</span>');
        // console.log($(this).val());
        $('#csr_' + x).prop('disabled', false);
    } else if (!$.trim(this.value).length) {  //input was emptied, clear the preview 
        $(this).closest('.form-row').find(".preview_domain").html(' ');
        } else { //Infalid input
        $(this).closest('.form-row').find(".preview_domain").html('<span class="d-block p-2"><i class="fa fa-times-circle text-danger"> <strong>' + thisValue + '</strong></i></span>');
        $('#csr_label_' + x).html('<span class="text-danger">*Please correct the domain name*</span>');
        $('#csr_' + x).prop('disabled', true);
        // console.log("failed");
    }
});
```